# Angular 6 - Click event is not firing

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to append a button to an angular table.

It shows the button but when a click on it, it doesn't fire the event.

This is my table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="GetGridData()">
  <!-- Rest removed for brevity.. -->

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Products">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Products </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="OnGetAllProducts(element.CategoryId)">See all products</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="GetGridHeader()"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: GetGridHeader();"></tr>
</table>
```

And this is what I've got on my ts:

```
export class DashboardComponent {
    // Rest of code removed for brevity.         

    // Row's events.
    //--------------
    OnGetAllProducts(categoryId: number) {
        alert("Listed");
    }
}
```

And this is my model:

```
export class Category {
    public CategoryId: number;
    public CategoryName: string;
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: It should work actually, Is `See all products` button visible in UI?

Comment: No, I don't see any error. Yea, it should. I still can't see why it doesn't. Been half a day on that.

Comment: Yea, it actually is visible. @BasavarajBhusani

Comment: One thing that I noticed is that, if i take the button out of the table, it works perfectly. It gets screwed up when I place it inside of the table.

Comment: Check in the F12 window. The button (or one of its ancestors) could have the style attribute: `pointer-events: none`. Or an invisible element may be on top of the button and prevent the click from reaching it.

Comment: It seems the problem lays on the `td` element, which is the inmediate parent of the button. When I inspect the button the `td` element is on top of it.

Comment: Forget what I said, the problem is the `mat-raised-button` attribute. I removed it and it worked fine. I put it back on and it got screwed again. Any ideas? :s

Comment: I think @ConnorsFan has the right idea. I believe it has something to do with the styles applied to the material table you're using. If you strip out all the mat-table directives from the table, everything works fine. Here is a simplified StackBlitz showing it work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itrb6w

Comment: did you find any solution? even I am facing the same. when button inside template, click event not working

Answer (score 4):

It's the `dataSource`. Your GetGridData() function is running constantly because you placed it in the template, which is re-rendering the table endlessly, which is why that's a bad practice. Instead, store the result in a variable and that's what you should pass as your dataSource.

Comment: Correct in my case. Was re-rendering the table as the button was clicked and therefore interrupting the click process. I've changed my getter to cache the array variable and return the same object unless the deriving parameters change. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. This saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;** verify correctness of styles

As many people can encounter similar problem and land here (like myself) I hope it wouldn't be a big offense when I post solution that worked for me in order to help next generations.

@BasavarajBhusani and others asked really good question, if `button is really visible from UI`.

The truth is that despite being physically visible, **my button slipped out of borders of the parent element**. After fixing styles by making parent element to dynamically adjust its size, it started to work well.

It is strange but the same layout worked well in AngularJS (1.X) but stopped after porting into Angular 6.